# The push refers to repository [docker.io/chatapp/monorepo] An image does not exist locally with the tag: chatapp/monorepo

Tags: docker, dockerfile, bitbucket, pipeline

I'm trying to push a Bitbucket repository to a private repository in Docker Hub as Docker image file. The build is successful to the point until I get this error:

```
docker push chatapp/monorepo
+ docker push chatapp/monorepo
The push refers to repository [docker.io/chatapp/monorepo]
An image does not exist locally with the tag: chatapp/monorepo
```

Does this have anything to do with how the `Dockerfile` inside the Bitbucket repository is written? Or are there some scripts missing in `bitbucket-pipeline.yml` file?
I'm new to Docker and I can't seem to figure this out.

Comment: If anyone comes here facing similar issue: I solved it by creating an access token for Docker Hub. For private repositories in Docker Hub, one needs to have access token enabled in local machine for creating pipelines.

Answer (score 0):

The error signifies that the image you're trying to push doesn't exist locally on the machine you're trying to push from. Run `docker images` and check if it's there, if not there's a problem with the pipeline creating it, if it does but with a different name try and fix that.

Comment: You're right, I don't have the image in local machine. Do I need to have it locally to push to Docker Hub? Doesn't the pipe created at Bitbucket repo do it directly? How do it create it locally to push it?

Comment: It sounds like it should've created it, does the pipe run locally or on the bitbucket server? If locally, consult the bitbucket pipeline documentation on the matter going forward

Comment: It runs on the Bitbucket server.

Comment: Then you should check what in the image creation process has gone wrong